# If A⊂B×C then B≠∅ and C≠∅

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given that statement:

> If $A⊂B×C$ then $B≠∅$ and $C≠∅$

It is said to be true. But if $B=∅$ and $C=∅$ and $A=∅$, why can't I tell that $∅⊂∅$, thus making the statement false? Assuming if $B=∅$ and $C=∅$ then $B×C=∅$.

Comment: The question is wrong.  The empty set is a subset of every set.  Are you sure there is no condition that $A\ne \phi$

Comment: Yes. It is just said to be like that "If A⊂B×C then B≠∅ and C≠∅".

Comment: Perhaps $\subset$ means "a strict subset" and excludes $A = B \times C$, as opposed to $\subseteq$

Comment: Henry, you are right. It is a strict one, without the = part, like $\subsetneq$

Comment: Then $\emptyset \not \subset \emptyset$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If  $\subset$ means "a strict subset" and excludes $A = B \times C$, as opposed to $\subseteq$,

then you can say $\emptyset \not \subset \emptyset$ and $A \not \subset \emptyset$

and so  $B \times C \not = \emptyset$ and thus $\exists (b,c) \in B \times C$

leading to $\exists b \in B$ and  $\exists c \in C$

and $B \not = \emptyset$ and  $C \not = \emptyset$